# Keep Texlive working during update?

Tags: texlive, updating

Several times I have had TeX files I couldn't compile while a `tlmgr update --all` was in progress. For example recently I got

```
ERROR: LaTeX3 Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.

--- TeX said ---
(LaTeX3)        Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted!
...
```

for a file that worked fine both before and after that update. I don't think this is a bug in Texlive but a deliberate shortcoming that we are meant to live with. (True, right? Otherwise it is my fault that I haven't reported this as a bug.) If you are the sole user of the system and you just started that update yourself there should be no surprises. For a multi-user system it can be worse. What's the best way to mitigate this? Is there a better way than making a total copy of the whole Texlive distribution, do the update in the copy and then switch to that 'atomically' afterwards?

Comment: Oh no, you mean during updates? Then you really have to wait until the formats are recreated.

Comment: Of course there are some simple policies to limit the inconvenience, such as doing updates during the night, or not updating very often (e.g., only 2 or 3 times per year), or maybe use the window manager to display a notice to the users that a backup is in progress and they have to wait a few minutes to recompile. Otherwise indeed you would need to resort to using two virtual machines (or similar) and switching them out.